# Can I have the shell ignore the command line sometimes but not always?

Tags: command-line, command, command-not-found

For debugging purpose sometimes I access a remote Linux box via VNC. At that time someone else may be working on that same Linux box through VNC and it may happen that I do not have facility to chat with that person. So essentially what happens is I start a new tab in the GNOME and type a message like this :

```
[xxx@slc04lyo abc]$ Hi this is X. I will use the box for some time
Hi: Command not found.
```

Is it possible to **not** have shell print the following?

```
Hi: Command not found.
```

If yes how can I do that selectively and not always? So that when needed I can use the shell as a raw chat platform?

P.S: I do not need to see an output. The other user is already in the VNC and can see what I typed. So the output is superfluous.

Comment: Don't do this _at all_. ssh into the box with your own account, use another X session via XDMCP, or many other possibilities.

Comment: Agree with @MichaelHampton that this methodology is seriously flawed in the first place.  You shouldn't be using VNC and shared accounts.  Linux was designed from the ground up with multiple users in mind; use it that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

End the line by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. It will look like

```
[user@box ~]$ Are you there?^C
```

**ETA:** <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> sends the signal SIGINT, which in this context basically means "stop what I'm doing and give me back a prompt". It's just the same as when you're running a program from your prompt and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> - it will kill the running program and give you your prompt back. Except in this case you've not actually started the program.

This can be useful in other situations too, e.g. when the cat has been having a dance all over the keyboard...

Comment: It does solve but can you explain in your answer why it works?

Comment: I added an explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Just comment out your message by prepending a `#` to it. This way nothing of what you write will be processed nor expanded by the shell.

```
[xxx@slc04lyo abc]$ # Hello, this is dog. I will use the box for some time
```

**Note:** If you forget to write the `#` first, you can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>#</kbd> to comment out the current line and get back to the prompt in a single move. This works with prompts using [`GNU Readline`](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), such as *bash*, *ksh*, *mysql*, *python*, *zsh* and many others.

Here's a short summary of [GNU readline's keyboard shortcuts](http://www.bigsmoke.us/readline/shortcuts).

Answer (score 5):

There is a `:` command that does nothing and ignores its arguments (way back when, it was used to tag labels for use by the `goto` command.)

```
$ : Hi this is X. I will use the box for some time
$
```

[Edit: As @llua points out, the shell will still parse the command line, so any unbalanced braces, quotes, backquotes, etc. will result in a continuation prompt, and semicolon, pipe, etc. will terminate the command.]

If you want to have a two-way chat with the other user, type `cat >/dev/null` and then type all you want; there will be no output other than what you type. Type <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to terminate the `cat`.

```
$ cat >/dev/null
Are you there?
yes I am.
^C
```

Comment: `:` or `#` in my case i would use the colon as the dash need me to type Caps + colon

Comment: normal parsing still happens, so `: Mark's answer` will cause the shell to wait for the ending `'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply type `echo Hi this is X. I will use the box for some time` no ?

If you want to avoid any output message you can also consider :
`echo Hi this is X. I will use the box for some time &> /dev/null` it will redirect the error and the output of this command in `null`. ==>no output at all.

You can also use the comment like this:
`# Hi this is X. I will use the box for some time`
if your using a shell that does not use `#` as comment mark just use the one you're used to.

Comment: `echo` still has an output. I do not need to see an output. The other user is already in the VNC and can see what I typed. so the output is superfluous.

Comment: @Geek using `#` does not work ?